# Why does an adjective not exist in "-ing" form when it already has an "-ive" form and vice versa?

Tags: adjectives

In other words, why is there *impressive* but no *impressing* and *haunting* but no *hauntive*?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: and there's adjective but no adjecting...:~)

Comment: Your one example is not *impressing* me.

Comment: @Laurel: in that sentence, "impressing" is a participle (or if you prefer, gerund-participle), not an adjective.

Comment: Some people use "[excitive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Excitive)," although ["excitative" is more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=excitive%2Cexcitative&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexcitive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexcitative%3B%2Cc0), and both of these are much less common than "exciting."

Comment: Oh, there's also "depressing" and "depressive."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely true to say that if there is an -ive form, there is no -ing adjective or vice versa.

It is true in some cases, but not all cases.

---

The absence of some -ive forms can be explained by looking at the etymology.

Most of our -ive adjectives come from the Latin -ivus. Of course, French got its -if (masculine) and -ive (feminine) suffixes from the same Latin words (and some of our -ive words came from French).

According to [WordHippo](http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/latin-word-for-9818cdbeac82981e960d65598f9dd31f124bc164.html), some Latin words for "haunting" are:

> adsum assum calco celebro concelebro frequento haunting obsideo opsideo pervolgo pervulgo

There is no -ivus word, so "hauntive" does not exist in English (or French).

---

On the other hand, there are plenty of times when both -ive and -ing forms exist as adjectives. When this is the case, one form may be obsolete, or the words may have subtly different meanings. The history is considerably more erratic, however.

Here are some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]